# Definition of higher partial derivatives.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

How does one rigorously define partial derivatives? If for $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ we define $$\frac{\partial^rf}{\partial x_1^{\alpha_1} \dots \partial x_n^{\alpha_n}},$$
where $\alpha_1 + \dots + \alpha_n = r$, as a result of differentiating $\alpha_n$ times w.r.t. $x_n$, $\alpha_{n-1}$ times w.r.t. $x_{n-1}$ and so on, how can we prove that this is the same as applying rth total derivative to corresponding basis vectors? I want something like
$$(D^rf)_p(e_{i_1})\dots(e_{i_r}) = \left(\frac{\partial^rf}{\partial x_1^{\alpha_1} \dots \partial x_r^{\alpha_r}}\right)_p$$
to be true.

Comment: What is this $\partial^n$ in the numerator?

Comment: @zhw, sorry, bad notation. Edited.